# Diagonalizing Matrix in Matlab Gives "Wrong" Linear Combination of Eigenvectors

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

In Matlab, I'm trying to solve for the energies and eigenstates of a Hamiltonian matrix which has a highly degenerate set of eigenvectors. The matrix is a 55x55 hermitian matrix, and when I call either `eig` or `schur` to do the diagonalization I find that some (but not all) of the eigenvectors are the "wrong" linear combinations within each degenerate subspace. What I mean by "wrong" is that there are additional constraints in the problem. In this case, there is a good quantum number, M, which I want to preserve by not allowing states with different M values to be mixed--- but that mixing is exactly what I see when I run the code. Is there a way to tell Matlab to diagonalize the matrix while simultaneously maintaining the eigenvectors of another operator?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `diag` to diagonalize a matrix and `[eig_vect,eig_val] = eig(A)` to give you eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know matlab well enough to know whether there is a routine for this this, but here's how to do it algorithmically:

First diagonalise H, as you do now. Then for each degenerate eigen-space V, diagonalise the restriction of C to V, and use this diagonalisation to compute simulaneous diagonalisations of C and H

In more detail:

I assume you have an operator C that commutes with your Hamiltonian H. If V is the eigen-space of H for a particular (degenerate) eigen value, and you have a basis x[1] .. x[n] of V , then for each i, Cx[i] must be in V, and so we can expand Cx[i] in terms of the x[], and get a matrix representation C^ of the restriction of C to V, that is we compute

```
C^[k,j] = <x[k]|C*x[j]> k,j =1 .. n
```

Diagonalise the matrix C^, getting

```
C^ = U*D*U*
```

Then for each row (r1,..rn) of U* we can form

```
 chi = Sum{ j | r[j]*x[j]}
```

A little algebra shows that this is an eigenvector of C, and also of H